# In SQLite, How do I exclude rows which contain certain strings?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's my SQLite table (in comma-delimited format):

```
ROWID,COLUMN
1,"This here is a string |||"
2,"Here is another string"
3,"And yet another string"
```

I want to exclude all rows under 'COLUMN' which contain '|||'. Is this possible in SQLite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from table where column not like '%|||%'
```

this should work

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where your_column not like '%'|||%'
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/32e44/1)